# Extra '/s/' at the end of Community URL

Tags: community

Can someone please help me understand why does Salesforce add a extra '/s/' to the Community URL?
We recently created an community using templates and whenever we try to access it, we notice that an '/s/' gets appended to the URL. Do we know why??

Example: Say if my community URL is https://mydomain.force.com/MyCommunity. Whenever I try to access this community, Salesforce adds an a /s/ at the end i.e https://mydomain.force.com/MyCommunity/s/

Answer (score 10):

The /s/ in a community URL (or at the end) means that the page was built using the community builder (site.com). Most of the new templates are built on top of the community builder.

URLs without the /s/ mean that they are force.com URLs (usually built using visualforce).

The help has some additional info: [Use Site.com to Customize Your Community](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_communities_using.htm&language=en_US)