# How can I call a RestResource through a Community site?

Tags: community, rest, restresource

I have a RestResource hosted at /services/apexrest/MyApi. I know that VisualForce pages have an alternative URL through the Community site e.g. /sfsites/c/apex/MyVisualForcePage. Does the same apply to RestResource and if so, what is the URL template?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, say your Apex REST endpoint is `azureEndpoint` by declaring it:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/azureEndpoint/*')
```

The path will be:

`/COMMUNITY/services/apexrest/azureEndpoint`. `COMMUNITY` is of course your community path. The host will be public "site" domain name (same as for your community).

**Do not** include the `/s` since that is not part of the community URL itself but only for the pages built on "Community Builder" (see [this for details](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98043/extra-s-at-the-end-of-community-url))

If your community does not have a path, then simply omit `/COMMUNITY`.

Depending on your access configuration the end point is available to guest users or authenticated only (determine this through the appropriate profile configuration).
Make sure you **do** make the Apex class available to the appropriate profile (for guest users, go through the Community -> Workspace -> Administration -> Pages -> "Go to Force.com Site" -> "Public Access Settings" configuration)!

Comment: I can't get it to work. My community path is https://xxx.force.com/s. This URL works: https://xxx.force.com/services/apexrest/MyApi. This URL returns "Invalid page": https://xxx.force.com/s/services/apexrest/MyApi

Comment: This does work. We're using it ourselves. I've updated my answer to make things more clear.